# Bootstrap center an image inside the div but without resizing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I need to place the image inside the div. I know there are img-responsive center-block classes but they resize the given image for some reason. Is there a way to achieve the same goal but without size distortions.

Note: the containing div is a bootstrap column with given classes: hidden-xs col-lg-9 col-md-6 col-sm-6.

Thank you

Comment: and is there any example of what you have tried yet?

Comment: Please make a fiddle so that we can help you in a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CSS is my friend**

can you try this CSS class

> HTML

```
 <img class="centerd-image" src="">

 or

 <div class="centerd-image">
      <img src="">
 </div>
```

> CSS

```
.centerd-image {
     margin: 0;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     margin-right: -50%;
     -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use css for the img class as

```
 width: --%;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
```